# K8ssandra on Existing on-prem k8 cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, k8ssandra

Is there a document where I can refer and deploy k8ssandra onto onprem k8 single cluster. This https://docs.k8ssandra.io/install/local/single-cluster-helm/ expects docker/mini kube to move forward. Is there a direct helm chart available.